# Start process and allow caller to end without waiting for process to finish

Tags: c#, process

I need to start a process from a C# console app and then allow the console app to finish/end without waiting for the process/thread to finish.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to avoid making your new process a child process of the current process:

```
ProcessStartInfo sinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
sinfo.UseShellExecute = true; // Do not wait - make the process stand alone
sinfo.FileName = "PathAndNameofExe";
Process.Start(sinfo);
```

Comment: This solution works for both .NET Framework and Core apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("TheNameOfTheOtherProcess.exe");
```

Comment: This only works on .NET Framework apps, where the default is to use ShellExecute. In Core UseShellExecute defaults to false. Please see the answer from @hans-karlsen for a solution that works in both.

Comment: @Nanki I mean sure, this doesn't apply to technologies that were created years after this question or answer were posted.  You seem to think that this question is a different question than the one that is actually is.

Comment: Not at all. Your answer was perfect at the time, it's just been superceded.